# Is there a known diophantine equation that describes the complement of the sums of 2 squares?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, arithmetic-geometry

It's well known by [Legendre's Three Square Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) that every natural number $n$ is either the solution of

$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = n$$

Or

$$ 4^{a}(8b+7) = n$$

But not both, where $x,y,z,a,b$ are all integers.

I am interested in a similar question but for the sums of two squares. We know that every natural number that is a sum of 2 squares has an even exponent for its prime factors that are $3 \mod 4$ via the [sum of two square's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem).

Unfortunately I haven't seen a diophantine characterization of these numbers. For me a characterization involves a finite number of variables $x_1 ... x_s$ and the operations $+,-,\times, /, \hat{\mkern6mu} $ and any complex numbers. At least [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A022544) doesn't seem to have one. Is anything known about this? If not a single equation then is there some FINITE set of diophantine equations $e_1, e_2 ... e_r$ such that every natural number that is not the sum of 2 squares is a solution to ONE of the equations of that FINITE set $e_i$ and not any other?

In other words do we have any way to characterize exactly the complement of the sums of 2 squares by diophantine equations?

Comment: Abstractly this must be possible by Matiyasevich's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich's_theorem

Comment: Yea so it must be tractable. I guess the interesting question is more along the lines of how few variables/polynomial degree is required. Moreover in the case of Legendre’s 3 square theorem, that form is extremely simple but non polynomial. The simplest polynomial form of the complement might be quite a bit hairier

Comment: I noticed that, when an integer cannot be represented as a sum of two squares, it can be represented as a sum of $3$ squares if we allow using negative integers. I haven't checked many numbers but if it is the case, then the solution is none other that your first equation for those numbers.
example: $7= 2^2 + 2^2 -1^2$. Or this one: $11=3^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$...

Comment: I don’t think that’s mutually exclusive with being a sum of 2 squares. A lot of integers that are a sum of 2 squares are also a sum of 3 squares. And integers that aren’t the sum of 2 squares may often be a sum of 3 squares. Edit: I think every odd number is difference of two squares so this less surprising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an odd natural number $n$ is not a sum of two integer squares then either
$$4a+3=n,$$
has a solution $a\in\Bbb{Z}$, or else the system
\begin{eqnarray}
(4a+3)(4b+3)&=&n,\\
(4a+3)x+(4b+3)y&=&1,
\end{eqnarray}
has a solution $a,b,x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$. Conversely, if this system does not have integral solutions for an odd integer $n$, then $n$ is a sum of two squares. To extend this characterization to all natural numbers $n$, simply take
\begin{eqnarray}
2^k(4a+3)&=&n,\\
\text{ or }\\
2^k(4a+3)(4b+3)&=&n,\\
(4a+3)x+(4b+3)y&=&1.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I like how you managed to encode the factorization via the Diophantine equations, and enforce the coprime condition.

Comment: Actually I think it can be simplified to the single system
\begin{eqnarray}
(4a+3)b&=&n,\\
(4a+3)x+by&=&1.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: In fact this then becomes a single diophantine equation $((4a+3)b-n)^2 + ((4a+3)x+by-1)^2 =0$.